# Line of C# code that always checking if a specific file exists but the message box is always showing, why is that?

Tags: c#, timer

My application successfully detects the specific file I want to detect but the messagebox always showing not only once but many times I dont know what is wrong.

Side question is this a good way of always checking if a certain file exists? or there is more better and accurate way? if there is any suggestions or link will be a great help . Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists(patch_to_checked))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File Found!");
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Also check the Filewatcher class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: @Amitd Okay thanks!. Any more links with more working examples? I'll read this

Comment: Yep.. Try these http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/filesystemwatcher-in-C-Sharp/ and http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial173_File-monitoring-using-FileSystemWatcher.html and http://www.sitedev.com/source/programmer/samples/watcher.asp

Comment: By the way, if you're needing a timer for this, you're surely doing something wrong.

Comment: @LMB, i thought so. I think I need Filewatcher ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should stop the timer as soon as you enter the function. Otherwise, the timer is ticking while the user is moving the cursor to the button to dismiss the message box:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();

        if (File.Exists(patch_to_checked))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File Found!");
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the timer before displaying the dialog box.

The reason for this is that while the dialog box is shown (modally), "timer reached" ("Tick") events are queued up. Then, when the dialog box is dismissed, another such message is delivered to your application causing the code to execute again, displaying the dialog box once more.

You could also work around this by displaying the message in a way that does not block the thread causing the display of the message, so that execution continues with the next statement immediately. But generally, it's best to just stop the timer while handling the `Tick` event if you need to perform modal or long-running operations.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     timer1.Stop();
     if (File.Exists(patch_to_checked))
     {
          MessageBox.Show("File Found!");
     }
    else
     {
        timer1.Start();
     }
}
```

it takes some time to redraw your screen, it redrawing but not feeling because of short interval of timer